# Parse error in pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, centos-7

Hope this is not as stupid a question as I think it is. But I'm in a loop and unable to find a solution.

I installed Postgres in centos machine. The installation worked fine (apparently). Now I have 3 Linux users - root, admin and postgres. In order to allow all connections I updated the pg_hba.conf file with necessary changes. Now, if I try to restart (from root or postgres user), I get below error:

```
-bash-4.2$ systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service
  ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===              
 Authentication is required to manage system services or units. 
 Authenticating as: Admin (admin) Password:
 ==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE === Job for postgresql-9.5.service failed 
 because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status 
 postgresql-9.5.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Please find below outputs:

```
-bash-4.2$ journalctl -xe 
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
  Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
  turn off this notice. No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.


-bash-4.2$ systemctl status postgresql-9.5.service 
 ● postgresql-9.5.service - PostgreSQL 9.5 database server    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)    **Active: failed** (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-07-25 12:58:51 IST; 1min 26s ago
 Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/   Process: 109849 **ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**   Process: 109843 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 102339 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I searched further and various links (most notably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492893/unable-to-start-postgresql-9-5-on-centos-7) ) pointed to the fact that I needed to run something like the below, which I did:

> /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb

But that would give error:

> Data directory is not empty!

The only way out of this is to delete the directory */var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data* completely, which would leave me with no DB and no pg_hba.conf

pg_hba.conf:

[image: Relevant part of pg_hba.conf]

Relevant error messages:

```
2018-07-25 12:53:06.218 IST >LOG: invalid authentication method "0.0.0.0/0" < 
2018-07-25 12:53:06.218 IST >CONTEXT: line 80 of configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf" < 
2018-07-25 12:53:06.218 IST >FATAL: could not load pg_hba.conf < 
2018-07-25 12:58:50.617 IST >LOG: invalid authentication method "0.0.0.0/0" < 
2018-07-25 12:58:50.617 IST >CONTEXT: line 80 of configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf" < 
2018-07-25 12:58:50.617 IST >FATAL: could not load pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: What errors appear in the Postgres log files? What changes did you make to `pg_hba.conf`? Does it work if you revert the changes?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Below is my pg_hba.conf relevant lines:

`# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all            0.0.0.0/0                md5`

Comment: If that’s all you have in the file then it’s not going to work. Read the comments. Restore the original and try again.

Comment: And below are logs (seems the issue is connected to my changes):

`< 2018-07-25 12:53:06.218 IST >LOG:  invalid authentication method "0.0.0.0/0"
< 2018-07-25 12:53:06.218 IST >CONTEXT:  line 80 of configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf"
< 2018-07-25 12:53:06.218 IST >FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
< 2018-07-25 12:58:50.617 IST >LOG:  invalid authentication method "0.0.0.0/0"
< 2018-07-25 12:58:50.617 IST >CONTEXT:  line 80 of configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf"
< 2018-07-25 12:58:50.617 IST >FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf`

Comment: The problem is a parse error in your configuration file

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have the complete pg_hba.conf file. I just posted the part which I changed. The rest of the file is as is.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Going by the error: "invalid authentication method "0.0.0.0/0"", my PostGres is somehow reading the ADDRESS  0.0.0.0/0 as my AuthenticationMethod and ignoring the md5 part of it. You seem to be correct, but any way to fix this issue. I double-checked the spaces on the line I edited, but still same result.

Comment: `local` means a local socket connection not via TCP/IP. Remove the 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: `initdb` should be done only once, as it name implies it create the low level database cluster structure, and certainly **NOT** after any failed restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> A record can have one of the seven formats
>
> local      database  user  auth-method  [auth-options] host
>   database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options] hostssl
>   database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options] hostnossl 
>   database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options] host
>   database  user  IP-address  IP-mask  auth-method  [auth-options]
>   hostssl    database  user  IP-address  IP-mask  auth-method 
>   [auth-options] hostnossl  database  user  IP-address  IP-mask 
>   auth-method  [auth-options]

Your line:

```
local all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

.. does not match any of these.

I suspect you want one of these instead:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

or:

```
local all all md5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phil. "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" is working and DB started fine. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again!